# Save Remote SSL Certificate via Linux Command Line

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, https, x509

Can you think of any linux command-line method for saving the certificate presented by a HTTPS server?  Something along the lines of having curl/wget/openssl make a SSL connection and save the cert rather than the HTTP response content.

The gui equivalent to what I'm looking for would be to browse to the HTTPS site, double-click on the browser "secure site" icon, and export the cert.  Except the goal here is to do it non-interactively.

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 50):

Something like:

```
openssl s_client -servername remote.server.net -connect remote.server.net:443 </dev/null | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' >/path/to/certificate.pem
```

That's what I use with fetchmail to retrieve the certificate of an SSL capable IMAP or POP3 server (except obviously I don't use port 443)

(Note that "redundant" `-servername` parameter is necessary to make `openssl` do a request with SNI support.)

Comment: Any way to get the full chain?

Answer (score 10):

From http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-retrieve

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# usage: retrieve-cert.sh remote.host.name [port]
#
REMHOST=$1
REMPORT=${2:-443}

echo |\
openssl s_client -connect ${REMHOST}:${REMPORT} 2>&1 |\
sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p'
```